# Detectar la eliminación de letra en JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

¿Cómo hago para detectar que se ha eliminado el contenido de un `input` con jquery, ejemplo:

Cuando escribo en el input el borde se pinta verde pero cuando borro sigue en verde, lo que debe pasar es que su estilo sea rojo `css`

Comment: Hola bienvenido, te recomiendo leer [ask], así como también hacer el [tour], si pudieras agregar algo que lleves hecho y dudas al respecto sería genial

Answer (score 1):

Fácil, solo debes detectar si el valor del `input` tiene longitud y pintar el borde de acuerdo al cumplimiento de esta condición, adicional usamos `keyup` para detonar la detección siempre que se presione una tecla dentro del input:

```js
$("#miTexto").on("keyup", function (){ //Supervisamos cada vez que se presione una tecla dentro.

  if($(this).val().length){ //Si el valor tiene longitud es porque existen letras o contenido dentro, así que pintamos verde
    $(this).css("border", "solid 3px green");
  } else { //En caso contrario pintamos rojo.
   $(this).css("border", "solid 3px red");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="miTexto">
```

Comment: Es funcional pero para mejor la estética podría reemplazar el `border` por `outline-color` asi `$(this).css("outline-color", "green");`, de esta manera no se vería un color azul junto con rojo o verde alrededor.

Comment: Gracias amgio, agradecido

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de hacer lo que esta necesitando es por medio del envento change() del Jquery el cual se activa cuando saldrias del foco del input y en esta parte evaluas si el campo ha sido eliminado su contenido. Con $(this) se evalua el input en curso/modificado.

$('input[type=text]').change(function() permite evaluar cualquier input text que tengas en el fomulario y aplicar la regla css de cambio de color

Aqui te dejo el codigo de ejemplo para el JQUERY  y HTML:

```js
  <script type="text/javaScript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // evento que se activa al cambiar el input y salir del foco
            $('input[type=text]').change(function() {
                if ($(this).val().length==0) {
                     // pone el borde ROJO si input esta vacio
                    $(this).css("border-color", "red");
                } else {
                     // pone el borde VERDE si input esta vacio
                    $(this).css("border-color", "green");
                }           
            });
        });
  </script>
```

```html
    <form>
        <label>dato2: </label>
        <input type='text' name="id1">
        <br><br>

        <label>dato2: </label>
        <input type='text' name="id2">
        <br><br>

        <label>dato3: </label>
        <input type='text' name="id3">
        <br><br>
    </form>
```